# How I create an event that will send for each registered different values

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-3.0

I am developing a card game.
In the start of the game each player gets five cards.
I want to create an event that each on of the players will register to it.
The event will be activated in the start of the game from a class called controller (the class who manage the game).
I want that this event will call the RecieveCards(CardList) of each player.

Each player should get diffrent cards...

The second option, and the simple one (without event), is to create a loop in the controller class that will run on all the players and for each player will call the ReciveCards(CardList).

I think that the first soultion is much more elegant, but I don't know how it is possible that it will send diffrent cards for each player it .. is there any pattern for it?

Edit: sorry, C# 3.0

Comment: I think the rule of thumb with design patterns is not to force a solution into a pattern.  Get it working first then refactor to patterns.

Comment: It is already working by loop... but it's look very ugly.. The issue is that I know how to program but this time I want to practice my design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to notify the prayers about the start of the game or you can use event approach. In this case when the event in raised a player should ask for his set of cards.

Comment: Is it right that the Player will ask for cards? The maanger should give him cards, it is not the player function to ask for cards...